# Conditions that ensure a bounded probability density function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable that is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. That means that $X$ has a PDF $f$. Are there simple conditions on $X$ that ensure that
$$
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(x) < \infty.
$$
with simple conditions. I mean for example, certain moment conditions or other tractable assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

Let the CDF be [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity).

If $|F(x)-F(y)|\leq K|x-y|$ for every $x,y\in\mathbb R$ and $g$ serves as PDF for the distribution then also the function $f$ prescribed by $x\mapsto\min(K,g(x))$ will serve as PDF of the distribution.

This with: $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}f(x)\leq K<\infty$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know a first moment of $X$ ensures that $F$ is uniformly continuous, is there a similar condition that implies that $F$ is Lipschitz?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot help you on such condition. If I meet one some day then I will let you know.